# node red cannot GET /myfile from directory

Tags: httprequest, node-red, node-request

I would like to ask.

I have file in **C:\users\nxf68958\.Node-red\report.html**

And when I would like to open this file by: **localhost:1880/report.html**
I get:
**Cannot GET /report.html**

in Log I have:  "Nov 09:52:00 - [info] User directory : \Users\nxf68958\.node-red"

I am using:
NR: 3.0.2
Node: 18.12.0

It worked perfectly on older versions of: NR: 2.2 and Node: 16.13.
Then I actualized and it stopped working.

In settings.js is option: "fileWorkingDirectory" I tried to change it, but without change.
What I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I fixed this issue by change "httpStatic" in settings.js by -> **httpStatic: __dirname,** but I am not sure if this is correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node-RED will not serve static files by default, you have to explicitly enable it by settings the `httpStatic` option in the `settings.js` file.

Settings the `httpStatic` value to point to the `userDir` (which is what you have basically done by setting it to `__dirname`) is a bad idea from a security point of view because this means anybody can download your `flows.json` and `flows_creds.json` files and the files like `settings.js` and `.config.runtime.json` (which holds the default encryption key for the creds file).

`fileWorkDirectory` is purely to set the default working directory for the code nodes that interact with the filesystem, it will have no effect on what files are served by the HTTP server.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. Now its much more clear for me. :) I am using reading also flows, because from there I am able to get programmatically flow name. In this case the security is not important. And I have one more question. When I am trying to load by HTTP GET reqeust  url:localhost:1880/flows and it does not work. But when I change localhost to 127.0.0.1 it worked well. (this occurred on W11, on W10 it worked even with localhost) do you know where should be a problem why from NR I can't call localhost but 127.0.0.1 is working? I thought that this is the same. Thank you